# JRuby + SWT + System Tray: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, swt, jruby, system-tray

I am trying to use JRuby to display tray item with SWT. I tried this with Windows 7, Ubuntu Unity/gnome 3/ and gnome classic.

I find that tray item doesn't come up. Also the menu is getting shown at the mouse cursor location.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
=begin
# references
* usage of swt gem -- https://github.com/danlucraft/swt/blob/master/examples/menu_and_toolbar.rb
* SWT tray example -- http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet143.java
=end

require 'java'
require_relative '../dependencies/swt/lib/swt'

class Doro
  include Swt::Widgets

  IMAGE = File.expand_path('../../assets/doro.jpg', __FILE__)

  def initialize
    ui_start
    setup_tray
    ui_end
  end

  def ui_start
    display = Display.get_current
    @shell = Shell.new
    #@shell.text = self.class.to_s
  end

  def ui_end
    #@shell.set_bounds(50, 50, 300, 200)
    #@shell.visible = false
    @shell.pack
    @shell.open
  end

  def setup_tray
    display = @shell.display
    tray = display.get_system_tray
    tray_item = TrayItem.new(tray, Swt::SWT::NONE)
    tray_item.tool_tip_text = 'Doro'
    tray_item.image = Swt::Graphics::Image.new(display, IMAGE)

    tray_item.add_selection_listener { }

=begin
    tray_item.add_show_listener { |event| puts 'show' }
    tray_item.add_listener(Swt::SWT::Show, Swt::SWT::Listener.new { |event| puts 'show' })
    tray_item.add_hide_listener { }
    tray_item.add_default_selection_listener { }
=end

    setup_menu tray_item

    tray_item.visible = true
  end

  def setup_menu(parent)
    menu = Swt::Widgets::Menu.new(@shell, Swt::SWT::POP_UP)

    fileItem = Swt::Widgets::MenuItem.new(menu, Swt::SWT::PUSH)
    fileItem.setText("File")

    editItem = Swt::Widgets::MenuItem.new(menu, Swt::SWT::PUSH)
    editItem.setText("Edit")

    menu.visible = true

    parent.add_menu_detect_listener do
      menu.each { |m| m.visible = true }
    end
  end

  def start
    display = @shell.display

    while !@shell.isDisposed
      display.sleep unless display.read_and_dispatch
    end

    display.dispose
  end
end

app = Doro.new
Swt::Widgets::Display.set_app_name app.class.to_s
app.start
```

UPDATE:

I saw this code without any change works on my Windows 7 m/c at work. I see the icon correctly. I am wondering why it didn't work on my windows at home. (Of course never on ubuntu). I used same version of SWT jars and swt gem.

Comment: I ask for a clarification; When you say: "it didn't work" it means that you get an error or that the program completes without any error, but the icon doesn't appear in the system tray ?

Comment: @Franco Rondini Program completes without any error, but the icon doesn't appear in the system tray.

Comment: does the java equivalent work?

Comment: @rogerdpack Haven't tried it. I will check it out and inform here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem in the way you refer to the TrayItem class:

```
def setup_tray
    ...     
    # tray_item = TrayItem.new(tray, Swt::SWT::NONE) # here is the problem, replace with above
    tray_item = org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem.new(tray, Swt::SWT::NONE)
```

this change makes the icon appears in the tray.

To show the menu when you right click the icon fix the setup_menu:

```
def setup_menu(parent)
    menu = Swt::Widgets::Menu.new(@shell, Swt::SWT::POP_UP)

   fileItem = Swt::Widgets::MenuItem.new(menu, Swt::SWT::PUSH)
   fileItem.setText("File")

   editItem = Swt::Widgets::MenuItem.new(menu, Swt::SWT::PUSH)
   editItem.setText("Edit")

   menu.visible = false # FIXED   
   parent.add_menu_detect_listener do
=begin # fixed debug code     
     items = menu.getItems
     puts "this code block run every time you rightclick the icon in the systray,"
     puts "your menu consists of #{items.count} items"
     items.each { |m| p m.text }
=end      
     # items.each { |m| m.visible = true } #original code
     menu.visible = true # FIXED
   end
end
```

For the way to refer to swt classes I refer to the article: [using swt with jruby](http://www.weblogism.com/item/255/using-swt-with-jruby) by *Sébastien Le Callonnec*

Otherwise, following the article of Martin Sadler: [An Introduction to Desktop Apps with Ruby](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/09/29/an-introduction-to-desktop-apps-with-ruby/) I found a solution based on AWT (not SWT)

with some edit:

1) include Java and import awt classes you need in your jruby class

```
class Doro
  include Java
  import java.awt.TrayIcon
  import java.awt.Toolkit
  ...
```

2) setup the menu and setup the tray icon in the setup_tray

```
 def setup_tray
    # Setup our menu items
    file_item = java.awt.MenuItem.new("File")
    edit_item = java.awt.MenuItem.new("Edit")
    # Add the items to the popup menu itself
    menu = java.awt.PopupMenu.new
    menu.add(file_item)
    menu.add(edit_item)
    # Give the tray an icon and attach the popup menu to it
    image    = java.awt.Toolkit::default_toolkit.get_image(IMAGE)
    tray_icon = TrayIcon.new(image, "Screenshot!",  menu)
    tray_icon.image_auto_size = true
    # Finally add the tray icon to the tray
    tray = java.awt.SystemTray::system_tray
    tray.add(tray_icon)
  end
```

tested on:

> OS: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>
> ruby interpreter: jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (IBM J9 VM 1.6.0) [Windows Vista-amd64-java]
>
> gem: swt (0.13)

Comment: That was exactly the article that motivated me to write my app in JRuby. But i want to use SWT. Not AWT.

Comment: @ragu.pattabi you're absolutely right! sorry. Just edited the answer with some hint for SWT

Comment: I saw Windows 7 m/c at work shows the icon correctly with the original code. When I came back here I see your suggestion of changing TrayItem to org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem which is one and the same since I mixed in Swt::Widgets to Doro. I am wondering why it didn't work on my windows at home. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Weren't you able to see the tray icon with the original code?

Comment: the original code fails in: NameError: uninitialized constant Doro::TrayItem
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2642

Comment: @ragu.pattabi I edit again: to show the menu when you right click the icon fix the setup_menu

Comment: Oh "Doro::TrayItem const_missing". I had a swt gem in submodule and found that it doesn't include TrayItem. I added that entry and put the pull request to the gem creator.

Comment: I will try out ur recent update and see if I get the icon in the tray. Thanks.